# xcode story board doesn't align for iphone 5

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

When I try on iPhone 6 or higher it works fine, but for 5 it simply doesn't align correctly. I haven't set any size for the controller.

[image]

Comment: Have you applied autolayout constraints in Any x Any size class ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected, you need to apply autolayout constrains on the subviews,
read here [auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/) and here [constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html)

By this they will be centered on all devices or look like the way you define the constraints.